# How to pass global CSS/JS to components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have components with some styles:

```
const styles = () => ({
  rootPaper: {
    marginBottom: '25px',
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
});
...
 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    <Paper className={styles.rootPaper} elevation={4}></Paper>
...
export default withStyles(styles)(...)
```

And it works. This code is repeated in some components so I want to exclude this as a separate JS file:

```
const globalCss = {
  rootPaper: {
    marginBottom: '25px',
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
  hidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },
};

export default globalCss;
```

and import that file like that:

```
import globalCss from '../../styles/globalCss';
...
<Paper className={globalCss.rootPaper} elevation={4}>
```

But when I want to use this in className it doesn't work(no errors). Used React v16 and Material-ui-next beta 20. How Can I move the same classes to one file and use it in different components?

Comment: Documentation for `withStyles`: https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component. Be sure you call `withStyles` in every component where you import styles objects and reference them like: `className={this.props.classes.rootPaper}`. I'd normally rather have styles locally within the component instead of importing though.

Comment: i'm not sure how your first example works. you are not invoking the `styles` function `className={styles.rootPaper}`. andshouldn't you pass it to `style` attribute instead of `className`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your 1st example actually works (as you mentioned).

1. You are not really invoking the `styles` function.
2. You should pass this kind of object to the `style` prop and not to
   the `className` prop (which accepts a string).

As for your second example, it should work if you will pass it to the `style` prop instead of the `className` prop, for reasons I mentioned above.

Running example:

```js
const globalCss = {
  rootPaper: {
    marginBottom: '25px',
    paddingTop: 0,
    color: 'red'
  },
  hidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={globalCss.rootPaper}>
    <h2>I got some styles!</h2>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```